# Inverse function of $f(x) = \frac{x+5}{x-2}$

Tags: functions, polynomials, inverse

Find the inverse of the function

$f(x) = \frac{x+5}{x-2}$

Here's what I have so far:

$y = \frac{x+5}{x-2}$

$x = \frac{y+5}{y-2}$

$(x)(y-2) = (y+5)$

but this seems to be a dead end.

How should I approach this?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you get the equation $$x=\frac{y+5}{y-2}?$$

Comment: Go on and solve for $y$.

Comment: @Aretino That's where I'm drawing a blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there:

$$x = \frac{y+5}{y-2}$$
$$x(y-2) = y+5$$
$$xy - 2x = y+5$$
$$xy - y = 5 + 2x$$
$$y(x-1) = 5+2x$$

I'll let you finish.

Comment: How do you get between the last two? I fixed the sign in my question -- thanks :)

Comment: Subtracted $y - 2x$ from both sides, then pulled $y$ out of the left side.  Edited my answer.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm just continuing from where you stopped

$(x)(y-2) = (y+5)$

$xy-2x = y+5$

$xy-y=2x+5$

$y(x-1)=2x+5$

$y=\frac{2x+5}{x-1}$

Comment: Your first line should read $x(y - 2) = y \color{red}{+} 5$.

Comment: thats silly of me

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Subtract  $\displaystyle\frac{x-2}{x-2}$ from the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: your function is a rational function that is a ratio of two linear functions. It's automatic that the inverse will be that same form.

Your function has a vertical asymptote at $x=2$ and a horizontal asymptote at $y=1$, so the inverse function swaps these. So $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{2x+k}{x-1}$ for some $k$. Your function has an $x$-intercept at $-5$, so the inverse has a $y$-intercept at $-5$, which means $k=5$. So $$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{2x+5}{x-1}$$